# sed unterminated address regex

Tags: perl, sed

the following sed command works in terminal but when I wanted to store the output into a variable in a script, it prompts me "*sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated address regex*" meesage. Not sure what is this...

```
Input file example:
orange
abc
def

apple
asd
edf
```

sed command to get keyword until brank line, this is working in terminal:

```
sed -n '/orange/,/^$/p' temp_stage.txt
```

Stored into a variable with the exact command. Not working.

```
my $waha = `sed -n '/orange/,/^$/p' temp_stage.txt`;
```

Comment: You have to escape the `$` sign: `my $waha = \`sed -n '/orange/,/^\$/p' temp_stage.txt\``;

Comment: Why on earth are you calling `sed` from `perl` that has all the regex:ing that `sed` has and more built-in? Do you want to include the blank line in `$waha` btw?

Comment: @ted an even better point! To the OP: you shouldn't be invoking external commands when there are more standard (in this case built-in) ways of doing the same thing. Invoking external programs is wasteful and inefficient.

Comment: @Blurman As you tagged this question in _perl_, I just recommend to do this task by reading a file line by line and if you encounter any blank line just _last_ the loop and store the read contents to any variable or file. That's all :)

Comment: I was thinking to reduce all lines into 1... I think I am wrong. Alright I will then proceed with reading the file line by line. Thanks thanks

Comment: Backtick literals act as double-quoted string literals. `$/` is being interpolated. which is you need to escape the `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version that doesn't use `sed` at all.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'temp_stage.txt';

my $waha;

open my $fh, $filename or die("$0: $filename: $!");
while(<$fh>) {
    # concatenate the lines from "orange" to blank (inclusive)
    $waha .= $_ if(/orange/ .. /^$/);
}
close($fh);

print "$waha";
```

See [perlop - Range-Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators) for the `..` operator used to capture the range.